# Custom Federation broker on azure and google

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, google-cloud-platform, amazon-iam

What could be an alternative to custom federation broker on aws in azure and google. In AWS I am able to create a url that permits federated user to login and access resources like this -

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_providers_enable-console-custom-url.html

How we could create the same in azure and google?

Answer (score 4):

This answer covers Google Cloud Platform.

The basic foundational identity for Google Cloud (GCP) is Google Accounts. This means that the users are required to have a Google Identity before you can setup federation / SSO. GCP IAM permissions are assigned to email addresses (User, Service Account, G-Suite Group, etc.).

Where AWS requires a custom URL for SSO, Google implements OAuth. This means once authenticated, users can just use Google services without needing special URL entry points. In this respect Google's SSO is smoother for end users.

GCP supports SAML 2.0 SSO. Google acts as the service provider and the third party (AD, Okta, etc.) act as the Identity Provider. This requires you to setup Google Cloud Identity.

I went thru this process and just like AWS, it can be complicated. One item to think about. Do you plan to use GCP as your primary cloud plaform or one of the other vendors. The reason is that if GCP is your primary platform, then everything will be a lot easier if you also implement G Suite first. However, if you are a Microsoft shop where you want Active Directory to be your Identity Provider, then SAML is the implementation path. Just be prepared that you will need to setup directory synchronization (connectors). Google has a good connector for Azure Active Directory. This [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ze6jWdfaLpg&feature=youtu.be&t=159) provides a good introduction to extending Active Directory to GCP IAM.

This article will take you step by step thru setting up the correct Google services, SAML SSO, setting up Identity Providers, etc.

[Using your existing identity management system with Google Cloud Platform](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/identity-security/using-your-existing-identity-management-system-with-google-cloud-platform)

Additional Reading:

[Google Cloud Identity](https://cloud.google.com/identity/)

[Setup SSO](https://support.google.com/a/answer/60224)

[Set up your own custom SAML application](https://support.google.com/a/answer/6087519)

Comment: Hi John, thanks for the clarification, actually we are working on a lab platform for our team where in team members can perform lab activity of google, azure and aws. We had already implemented for aws using custom url, but not very much sure how to have the same kind of federation for google and azure. Incase of aws customer gets auto logged into aws platform with custom url. Can you point us in right direction.

Comment: I provided you with documents to review. The first one takes you step by step thru the process for Google.

Comment: @prasoon are you able to achieve this?