# GCP Custom Federation URL for Playground

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-cloud-platform, cloud, service-accounts

I have created a Service Account to impersonate users, I have generated Access token for that. I am trying to create custom URL to allow users to direct login to Console. Same thing I have done using Custom Identity Broker.

My agenda is to give Access to GCP Console to no. of users (dynamic) for limited amount of time to play with the resources. I have a script to clear the resources later on.

If Custom URL is not possible then if anyone can suggest possible methods of doing this?

Comment: A similar topic has been discussed here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54158217/11602913. Could it be an answer to your question?

Comment: @mebius99 I already check that post, but that doesnt answer my question.

Comment: That answer actually describes how Google IAM differs from AWS. Instead of manipulating custom URLs you can manage permissions in a convenient way: grant permissions to the Google-identified users and later revoke them as needed. This approach could address the concerns from the original question: 1) "give Access to ... no. of users"; 2) "for limited amount of time".